# Why does the WPF TreeView control inherit from ItemsControl instead of Selector?

Tags: wpf, treeview, selector, itemscontrol

Looking at the inheritance chart for WPF controls I notice something unexpected for the TreeView control. Other controls that allow user selection inherit from either the Selector or MultiSelector base class. This makes sense as the Selector class adds selection capabilities to the base ItemsControl class. So I was expected that the TreeView would likewise inherit from that same class, but it does not. It inherits from ItemsControl directly. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the selection of the tree-items must be managed along the whole hierarchy, and not only along the root-level items. The Selector class keeps track of a flat-list. The fact is that an hierarchy structure must be treated in a particular way.

Comment: Well, as far as I see the problem the selector only adds properties to query selected items, and that's what you will have in a TreeView, selected items.

Comment: @SoMoS: I'm not sure to understand your point. Consider a basic TreeView app, where the items have to be styled upon the IsSelected property. Now, if the Selector was implemented at root level, how could you map the properties along the template hierarchies?